# C++ class how to avoid conflicts of fcntl open with self-defined open function

Tags: c++, function, class, namespaces

I defined a class below to operate uart:

```
class UART : public IHALResource<std::string, uart_config> {
   private:
    const std::string PORTNAME;
    int fd;

   public:
    int32_t open() override;
    UART(std::string portName) : PORTNAME(portName){};
    ~UART();
};

int32_t HAL::UART::open() {
    fd = open(PORTNAME.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error opening %s: %s\n", PORTNAME.c_str(), strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The open() function in UART open method, I hope use open function from fcntl not from UART class. But the result seems oppsite.

Can Anyone tell me how to distinguish these two "open" function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Specify the namespace? I dunno what the fcntl thing is exactly but presumably it's in a separate namespace otherwise you'd get a compiler error

Comment: But what is fcntl's namsespace? I can't found it.

Comment: Looks like it's some kind of Linux operating system thing, probably `::open` to use the global namespace

Comment: Thanks @Tas ! That's correct. Thanks for your help. And maybe you should make it as an answer, I'll accept it.